# Could you please help me phrase a question?

Tags: phrases, questions

I would be grateful if you could help me figure out the right way to say some phrases in English. I have been wondering for a long time how to ask a client about the number of days he wants to rent a car. I say it in two different ways:

1. How long do you want to rent a car for?
2. How many days do you want to rent a car?

Are any of these sentences correct? What would be the right way to say it?

Thank you in advance))

Comment: We don't need "car" in the question because it's obvious from the context.  Thus: *How long do you need the rental?* or *How many days will you need it?*

Comment: You can always ask:  When do you want to pick it up?  And: When will you bring it back?

Answer (score 1):

Both are fine. Brits might use 'hire' instead of 'rent' but should still understand the question.

2 probably better to start with 'For'.

Comment: No, Brits say *hire*; Americans, *rent*.

Comment: Damn! I'm a Brit who lived in the States for a while and now rent sounds correct to me! I will amend my answer. Thanks.